# Sending Request to Server (File) Using ReactJS and Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel

this is my first time creating upload file in reactjs and my server is laravel.
I have problem regarding uploading files.

I try to use the console to detect if is their changes happen when i upload file.
yes probably the file is show in my console.

however in my server i use the hasFile of laravel it says that. **No file found.**

1. Why No File found server detect
2. Why the status is **OK**
3. Lastly in my console found that i upload file, but in the server detect that no file found.

[image: Sample Image]

My Controller

```
public function save_home_content(Request $request)
{

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        echo 'Have File';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'No File';
    }


}
```

My Input

```
<div className="col-md-6" id="file-content">
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlFile1">Image</label>
        <input type="file" 
        name="image"
        onChange={this.handleChangeImage}
        className="form-control-file" 
        accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" 
        id="exampleFormControlFile1"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

My handle

```
    handleChangeImage(e){
    this.setState({
        image:e.target.files[0]
    })

    console.log(e.target.files);
}
```

Axios

```
        axios.post('/api/save_home_content', this.state.image).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => (error.response));
```

Regards..

Answer (score 0):

for upload image with react js and laravel you must first of all add this `encType="multipart/form-data"` to the `<Form>` componenet after that in axios request do like this and add important thing `headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },`

this is result code for upload image with laravel and react js

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', this.state.image);
    formData.append('name', this.state.name);
    formData.append('family', this.state.family);
    formData.append('body', this.state.body);
    formData.append('email', this.state.email);
    formData.append('phone', this.state.phone);
    formData.append('subject', this.state.subject);

    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/contact_us',
        formData,
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },

        }
        )}
```

> the key to solving your problem is just add 
>    headers: {
>                       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
>                   },
>   to your axios request 
>   hope work for you:)